# Adjusting Floyd Rose Action - Bridge is Lower On Treble Side

Tags: setup, action, tremolo-system

I am adjusting the action on my Floyd Rose Special.  In order to get the action low enough on the treble side - I had to lower it a bit.  Is it normal that the treble side of the tremolo is lower/recessed while the bass side not?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since the treble strings are thinner in gauge, they won't need as much room to vibrate, so, yes, they can be set lower than the thicker bass strings, on most guitars with adjustable saddles.